# Get real time heart rate data from Jawbone UP3 device using BluetoothGatt

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, jawbone

I have used BluetoothGatt sample app from Android samples app. Now, my requirement is to access heart rate data from UP3 device using BluetoothGatt connection. Sample app have already declared UUID for heart rate measurement characteristic. UP3 device is getting connected with Android device and UUID of services and characteristics are being displayed in list. But from that device the UUID for heart rate measurement is not displaying.
So, my concern is that how to read heart rate from UP3 device or what other mechanism I can use? Please somebody reply.

Answer (score 2):

For heartrate data, Jawbone does not recommend trying to read the Bluetooth data directly. Instead, the Jawbone UP API provides a [heartrate endpoint](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/endpoints/heartrate) to access a user's resting heartrate measurements over a given time period.

For additional details on how to create an application and use the API, please visit the [Jawbone Developer Portal](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/).

Comment: I know this but my requirement to access real time heart rate data from UP3 device.

Comment: @RAY And how to get the passive heart rate? I want different values throught the day and not just one like the resting heart rate. I wanted realtime but I think is not possible...

Comment: @SamuelMéndez could you provide some details on what you want to use the heart rate data for? Jawbone has some APIs that we make available to researchers that aren't yet ready our developer portal. You can send details to research@jawbone.com

Comment: @RAY I already sent an email to apisupport@jawbone.com. I want to get the instant value or the last heart rate measured value when I requested, not just one single measure for the entire day. That way I can know better the user's pattern throughtout the day

Comment: @SamuelMéndez responded to your email.

Answer (score 1):

The up3 probably doesn't know the heart rate in a usable form. Wearables have very limited energy budgets, and the up3 has sensors that pick up a lot of things from a few sensors. DSP on that data is likely done in the cloud, which is why you get a (probably) restful api from jawbone, their fancy technology is in the algorithms, so to get a numerical heartrate you have to get it from them.